Equivalent Forms of Schur-Weyl Duality?
I'm trying to understand Schur-Weyl Duality, and in doing so have encountered two statements which various sources refer to as "Schur-Weyl Duality".
The first I encountered was the statement that the dth tensor power of a vector space V can decomposed as $$V^{\otimes k} \cong \bigoplus_{D} V_D \otimes \mathcal{S}_D(V)$$
The other decomposition I have seen is that
$$V^{\otimes k} = \bigoplus_D \mathcal{S}_D(V)^{\oplus m_D}$$
where $V_D$ is a representation of the symmetric group $S_k$, $\mathcal{S}_D(V)$ is the Gl(V) representation obtained by the image of the Young symmetrizer on $V^{\otimes k}$, $m_D$ is the dimension of the corresponding representation $V_D$, and the sums are indexed by Young Diagrams corresponding to representations of $S_k$.
My assumption is that these are equivalent formulations, or that one is a corollary of the other, but I'm not sure how to see it. If anyone can explain it to me, I'd greatly appreciate it!

Since $V_D$ is a $m_D$-dimensional space, abstractly it is isomorphic to $\mathbb C^{\oplus m_D}$. Thus
$$V_D\otimes S_D(V)\simeq \mathbb C^{\oplus m_D}\otimes S_D(V)\simeq S_D(V)^{\oplus m_D}$$
as representations of $GL(V)$. So the first expression implies the second.
